calculating the average of column that is not a number
So I have 2 sheet, the first one contains student's name, subject, and their grade.
Sheet1 :



A
B
C




Mark
Math
A


Dave
Physic
C


Carol
Math
B


Dave
P.E
B


Carol
Physic
A


Mark
Physic
A



The second one is the grading system used :
Sheet2:



A
B




A
4


B
3


C
2


D
1



And the third sheet is the average grade of each student.
Sheet3:



A
B




Mark
4.0


Dave
2.5


Carol
3.5



I accomplished this by adding another column to the first sheet that use a vlookup function. Can we make the third sheet directly without adding another column to the first sheet?

was there a specific question about your homework that you had?

You could try using the following formula:


=LET(
     a, XLOOKUP(C2:C7,E2:E5,F2:F5),
     b, A2:A7,
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(c, MAP(c, LAMBDA(d, AVERAGE(FILTER(a,d=b))))))


Explanations:

Using LET() function define variables so as to reduce repeated calculations and reduce redundancy as well.
Variable a is using XLOOKUP() function to return the grade values.
Variable b is the range of names.
Variable c uses UNIQUE() function to return unique values of the above.
Using BYROW() or MAP() to write up a custom function which calculates with the help of LAMBDA() to return one single dynamic array as output. The custom calculations applied here with the help of AVERAGE() and FILTER() function. FILTER() function extracts grade values per each unique names and averages it using the former function.
Lastly, wrapping within a HSTACK() function to merge both the unique names c and the output of averages returned using the BYROW()/MAP() function to get the ultimate desired output.


In the context of your OP, the formula applied to the third sheet will be like as below:
=LET(
     a, XLOOKUP(Sheet1!C2:C7,Sheet2!A2:A5,Sheet2!B2:B5),
     b, Sheet1!A2:A7,
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(c, MAP(c, LAMBDA(d, AVERAGE(FILTER(a,d=b))))))



You may also use Power Query.

Click Data > From File > From Excel Workbook > Browser your workbook > Tick "Select multiple items", select 2 tables > Click "Transform Data".


Go to Home tab > Combine group > Merge Queries > Merge Queries. Then select column C in table 1 to match column A in table 2 > Click OK.

There will be a new column added in table 1. Click the expand icon, and select column B to expand.

Go to Home tab > Transform group > Select Group By. The data can be grouped by column A of table 1. Besides, we may add 2 new columns, one is the sum of grades, another one is the count of subjects.

Click Add Column tab > Custom Column > Enter =[Sum]/[Count].

Then you may load the query to a new sheet.

If names are given in column A of Sheet3 you can use a traditional formula:
=AVERAGE(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6=A1,LOOKUP(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$6,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4)))

